# Python: if/elif function that continues through script when False?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, dictionary, return

EDIT:

I ask a user a set of questions from a dictionary:

```
questions = {
  "strong": "Do ye like yer drinks strong? ",
  "salty": "Do ye like it with a salty tang? ",
  "bitter": "Are ye a lubber who likes it bitter? ",
  "sweet": "Would ye like a bit of sweetness with yer poison? ",
  "fruity": "Are ye one for a fruity finish? "
}
```

These keys are associated with another dictionary:

```
ingredients = {
  "strong": ["glug of rum", "slug of whiskey", "splash of gin"],
  "salty": ["olive on a stick", "salt-dusted rim", "rasher of bacon"],
  "bitter": ["shake of bitters", "splash of tonic", "twist of lemon peel"],
  "sweet": ["sugar cube", "spoonful of honey", "splash of cola"],
  "fruity": ["slice of orange", "dash of cassis", "cherry on top"]
}
```

and I ask them the questions through a "simple" if/elif set for each question, and assign their answers to a new dictionary:

```
beverage = {}


def drink():
  """Find out user preferences and assign to new dictionary"""
  if raw_input(questions["strong"]).lower() == "yes":
    beverage["strong"] = ingredients["strong"]
  elif raw_input(questions["strong"]).lower() == "no":
    return False
  if raw_input(questions["salty"]).lower() == "yes":
    beverage["salty"] = ingredients["salty"]
  elif raw_input(questions["salty"]).lower() == "no":
    return False

...


drink()
```

And lastly print beverage:

```
print beverage
```

If the user says "yes" it all works well.

BUT, if the user answers "no", the first question is asked again (presumably because of my if/elif structure using raw_input()), and then just skips all the other questions completing the script.

How do I structure it so that if the user says "no" to the first question, it then asks the next question and not each question twice?

printout:

```
Do ye like yer drinks strong? yes                                                                                                                                            
Do ye like it with a salty tang? no                                                                                                                                          
Do ye like it with a salty tang? yes                                                                                                                                         
Are ye a lubber who likes it bitter? no                                                                                                                                      
Are ye a lubber who likes it bitter? yes                                                                                                                                     
Would ye like a bit of sweetness with yer poison? no                                                                                                                         
Would ye like a bit of sweetness with yer poison? yes                                                                                                                        
Are ye one for a fruity finish? no                                                                                                                                           
Are ye one for a fruity finish? yes                                                                                                                                          
Yer cocktail is a made of a                                                                                                                                                  
['glug of rum']
```

Comment: `or "yes"` means if "yes" == True and "yes" is always True

Comment: Should I use separate functions for each questions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your conditionals like so:

```
raw_input(questions["strong"]) in ("Yes", "yes")
```

Alternatively, you can try checking one case:

```
raw_input(questions["strong"]).lower() == "yes"
```